# Upgrade to Grails 2.0: /index.gsp not found

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, run-app

I have upgraded from Grails 1.3.7 to 2.0.0.RC1:

After sorting out a lot of issues with depdendencies I have finally managed to start my Grails application but when browsing to URL it tell me I receive the following:

```
GroovyPagesServlet:  "/index.gsp" not found
```

It worked perfectly before... where is it looking for it?

Thanks

Jonas

Comment: My UrlMappings.groovy has got the following entry
`"/"(view:"/user/login")`
this view and controller exists and when browsing straight to `<host>:<port>/<appName>/user/login` it works.

Any ideas why the _UrlMappings_ does not work?

Answer (score 3):

ok, I figured it out. The above syntax in `UrlMappings.groovy` does not work. It must be:

```
"/" {
  controller = "user"
  action = "login"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As I add SecurityFilters.groovy due to official docs, the same thing happens. Tomcat show error: "/index.gsp" not found
Please see also:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filterTypes

```
class SecurityFilters {
   def filters = {
       loginCheck(controller: '*', action: '*') {
           before = {
              if (!session.user && !actionName.equals('login')) {
                  redirect(action: 'login')
                  return false
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Actually, I think the official doc make a mistake. After

```
redirect(action: 'login')
```

it should be

```
return true
```

Comment: I believe that the return value dictates whether Grails should proceed to process the requested controller action.

Answer (score 1):

Edit `UrlMappings.groovy`, add this，eg:
`/errorInfo.gsp` (view: `/errorInfo`)

ref from : 
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Direct-linking-to-gsp-in-Grails-2-0-td4228929.html