# Grails 2.1.1: Redirect to /index.gsp not working with Filter defined

Tags: grails, redirect, filter

I have a Grails 2.1.1 application which runs fine, at least until I try to define a filter for all `Controller` to redirect to the `index.gsp` if `user` is not set in the `session` variable...

what ever I try, I'm not able to redirect to "/index", nor render "/index" when starting the server - if I remove the filter and redirect to "/index" from my `AuthenticationController` on false parameters, all works like charm...

so, here's what I have so far:

```
class AuthenticationFilters {
  all(controller:'*', action'*') {
    before = {
      def user = (User) session.getValue("user")
      if(user == null || !user.loginState) {
        redirect(controller: 'authentication', action: 'index')
        return false
      }
    }
  }
}

class AuthenticationController {
  def authenticationService

  def index = {
    render(view: '/index')
  }

  def login(LoginCommand cmd) {
    if(cmd.hasErrors()) {
      redirect(action: index)
      return
    }
  }
  ....
}
```

now, if I comment out the `all` Filters definition, everything works well. I got the page (index.gsp) shown on start up and if the `LoginCommand` has errors, I'm redirected to the `index.gsp` page without any problems.
if I now comment in the `all` Filters definition, I get a `404`.

I tried:
[Grails: Redirect to index.gsp that is not in any controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144775/grails-redirect-to-index-gsp-that-is-not-in-any-controller)
[Upgrade to Grails 2.0: /index.gsp not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089592/upgrade-to-grails-2-0-index-gsp-not-found)
[Grails: what are the main issues (and his solutions) when deploying in weblogic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193390/grails-what-are-the-main-issues-and-his-solutions-when-deploying-in-weblogic)

but I didn't had any luck...

I'm developing on Intellij IDEA 11.1.4 Premium (evaluation)

---

**EDIT:** I tried to get the `User` object from the `session` property in my `AuthenticationFilters` class, surrounded by a `try/catch` block and now facing the problem that obviously the `session` property is not available? why?

```
try {
        def user = (User) session.getValue("user")
        if((user == null || !user.loginState)) {
            ...
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        println("... couldn't get user from session! ${e.getMessage()}")
    }
```

console output:

```
... couldn't get user from session! No such property: session for class: grailstest001.AuthenticationFilters
```

any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, just to add my experience here to close this question as solved and for further usage for other users:

to check if the user is entering the page for the first time, you could easily do this by checking for the `controllerName` field. It should be `null` or `""` (empty String) if the user was not referred to the site by any controller.

Also, I'm not using any Database within my application for authentication because all of this issuses are backended by an API. So I created a `UserService.groovy` class which is acting as a `SessionScopedBean` and I store all my user related infos within this class.

So, your filter definition could look like:

```
class MyFilters {
  def filters = {
    before = {
      if(!controllerName || controllerName.equals("")) {
        redirect(controller:'home',action:'index')
      }
      if(!applicationContext.userService?.getUser() || !applicationContext.userService?.getUser.isLoggedIn) {
        redirect(controller:'auth',action:'login')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to redirect the user which 'freshly' entered your page from within your `Filters.groovy` class, you could use the `UrlMappings.groovy` class to do so. Just map your `/` (root) index to the page you want:

```
class UrlMappings {
  static mappings = {
    "/"(controller:'mycontroller',action:'myaction') // change it to your liking
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?" {
      constraints {
        // apply constraints here
      }
    }
    "500"(view:'/error')
  }
}
```

Comment: Damn this was an annoying problem. The second part of your answer helped me out. Thanks!

Comment: This is a bug of grails. some one should file a bug to them.

Comment: thanks @Shawn for raising a JIRA, didn't think of it to be a Grails bug at least...

Answer (score 1):

I think your filter syntax may be incorrect - try

```
Class AuthenticationFilters {
  def filters = { // <--- added this
    all(controller:'*', action'*') {
      before = {
        def user = (User) session.getValue("user")
        if(user == null || !user.loginState) {
          redirect(controller: 'authentication', action: 'index')
          return false
        }
      }
    }
  } // <-- added
}
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't copy the code but wrote it down as I thought I knew what to write... forgot the `filters` definition. I do have exactly what you've written and it still doesn't work. do I have a deadlock here? why is the `index.gsp` page rendered (on startup, without filters) although there is no controller defined?